# In Ubuntu 16.04 (32-bit) browsers (Firefox, Opera) work extremely slow.

Tags: internet

After installing the system this problem occurs. Uget works correctly. I can download packages from the terminal without any problems. Only browsers work  slow. I can open only google.com and text versions of the sites. I have re-installed the system. I saw no difference.

Comment: What are the specs of your system? In particular, CPU, RAM, GPU, audio cards and driver in use are fundamental for these problems.

Comment: CPU: DualCore Intel Celeron B800, 1500 MHz (15 x 100)
RAM: 2 Gb DDR3-1333 DDR3 SDRAM  (8-8-8-22 @ 609 MHz)  (7-7-7-20 @ 533 MHz)  (6-6-6-17 @ 457 MHz)  (5-5-5-14 @ 380 MHz)
Motherboard: Lenovo 20079
Video adapter: Intel(R) HD Graphics Family  (787384 Kb)
Audio adapter: Conexant Cx20590 @ Intel Cougar Point PCH - High Definition Audio Controller [B-3]
Audio adapter: Intel Cougar Point HDMI @ Intel Cougar Point PCH - High Definition Audio Controller [B-3]      Laptop: Lenovo G570